# Detecting a module for the free group algebra on a finite quotient

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, ra.rings-and-algebras, finite-groups, group-rings

Let $F_2$ be the free group on two generators $x,y$ and let $R$ be the group algebra $\mathbf{Q}[F_2]$.  Let $a,b,c$ be integers.  Then define a right $R$-module

$M = R / (ax + by + c) R$.

I am interested in the question of whether $M$ is "detected" by finite quotients of $F_2$.  That is; given $(a,b,c)$, does there exist a surjection $f$ from $F_2$ to a finite group $G$ such that $M \otimes_{\mathbf{Q}[F_2]} \mathbf{Q}[G]$ is nontrivial?  There are some necessary conditions that aren't hard to check; for instance, a,b,c need to satisfy the triangle inequality with respect to any valuation on $\mathbf{Z}$.  But are these conditions sufficient?  For example, what if $(a,b,c) = (5,6,7)$; how would I check in this case whether $M$ is detected on some finite quotient of $F_2$?

Of course I am also interested in other elements of R, not just linear combinations of $x,y$, and $1$; but this seems like the simplest interesting case.

**Remarks:**

1. This question has a lot in common with [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/182231/detecting-invertible-elements-in-group-rings-by-their-images-for-finite-quotient); but in the older question, we are really asking about *integral* group rings, where invertibility is harder to come by.
2. The question is also related (at least in my mind) to questions about virtual positive Betti number for a finitely presented group $\Gamma$; in that case, Fox calculus gives a uniform presentation of the abelianization of the kernel of a quotient map $f: \Gamma \rightarrow G$ as a $\mathbf{Q}[G]$-module, which, if the virtual Betti number is positive, is nontrivial for some finite $G$.
3. One might also think of this question as having something to do with a "non-abelian Manin-Mumford conjecture."  Note that if $F_2$ were replaced with $\mathbf{Z}^2$, the question would ask about the intersection between torsion points in $\mathbf{G}_m^2$ and the line $ax+by+c=0$.  Manin-Mumford tells us that this intersection is finite.  Is there a similar finiteness statement in this case?  I guess this might say something like:  is there a finite set of finite quotients $G_1, ... G_k$ such that any finite quotient of $F_2$ detecting $M$ has some $G_i$ as a quotient?

Comment: Let $G$ be a finite quotient of $F_2$. The $R=Q[F_2]$ maps onto both $Q[G]$ and $M$. What do you call "the projection of $M$ to $Q[G]$" (at first glance it would make sense if $M$ were a submodule rather than a quotient of $R$)?

Comment: @YCor.  Maybe by "projection", Jordan means $M\otimes_{\mathbf{Q}[F_2]} \mathbf{Q}[G]$.  Maybe Jordan is asking whether there exists a quotient $F_2\to G$ such that this tensor product module is a nonzero (right) $\mathbf{Q}[G]$-module.

Comment: Yes, sorry, this is what I'm saying.  I will modify the post to clarify.

Comment: OK thanks (btw, I don't think the tag **gt** is justified: most likely people subscribing to **gt** and neither **gr** nor **ra** will not be interested)

Comment: I only subscribe to **gt** and I'm interested.  
So for example, by taking $G$ to be the 3-element group, we get that triples of the form $a=b=c$ or $a+b+c=0$ are acceptable (those being irreducibles in $\mathbb{Q}[G]$.)  In general, your condition says that, for some finite $G$ with two generators $x$ and $y$, $a+bx+cy$ is contained in a proper submodule of $\mathbb{Q}[G]$; that is, in some combination of subrepresentations of the regular representation which isn't all of them.  
(Just trying to reword the problem in lots of ways...)

Comment: Yep, this is the way to phrase it to make it sound like a question about representations of finite groups (which I couldn't do...)

Comment: @Fedya anyway this would fit into **rt** instead (or possibly the purpose of **gt** is to consider questions about group algebra for people not subscribing to lists abouts groups or algebras :)

Comment: @JSE, what's the group $\Gamma$ in your remark 2? We know quite a lot about virtual Betti numbers these days.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see a good way to interpret my actual question in terms of a virtual Betti number of any   Γ.  But the thing you do when you compute the abelianization of the kernel of a map   Γ -> G is sort of LIKE what I'm asking:  by Fox calculus, you have an exact sequence M' -> M -> M'' in the group algebra of   Γ, you tensor everything with Z[G] and you take the cohomology in the middle.  (Assuming I have this right.)